# BrowserRouter ignoring forceRefresh prop when it's a variable

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm attempting to be smart about when I force my React SPA to refresh. I noticed `react-router-dom` has a handy `forceRefresh` prop. Great! Except... I can't get it to work when I use a variable as its value.

When hard-coded to `true` everything works as expected, navigating from route-to-route always forces a refresh.

I've put together simple [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/browserrouter-ds38c?file=/src/App.js) to illustrate the problem I'm having. As you can see, you can toggle `shouldRefresh` state variable to `true` (with button), but the app never refreshes on route change. React Developer Tools displays the correct prop for `BrowserRouter`, so I'm not really sure why making this value a variable doesn't work. Clearly the component is re-rendering with the new prop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the `forceRefresh` value is passed into the history object's constructor, so it cannot be dynamic the current implementation of `react-router-dom` (v5). [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7637)